# react/typescript: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, typescript, redux

When I try this sample code from react-bootstrap, I keep getting errors such as " Parameter 'context' implicitly has an 'any' type; "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'."

in form.tsx:

```
class FormExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      value: ''
    };
  }

  getValidationState() {
    const length = this.state.value.length;
    if (length > 10) return 'success';
    else if (length > 5) return 'warning';
    else if (length > 0) return 'error';
    return null;
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <FormGroup
          controlId="formBasicText"
          validationState={this.getValidationState()}
        >
          <ControlLabel>Working example with validation</ControlLabel>
          <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={this.state.value}
            placeholder="Enter text"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <FormControl.Feedback />
          <HelpBlock>Validation is based on string length.</HelpBlock>
        </FormGroup>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default FormExample;
```

in Jumbo.tsx:

```
const Jumbo = () => (
   <FormExample />
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735288/why-does-parameter-props-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In *typeScript* you should install [@types/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) and while extending the `React.Component` you need to specify the `props` and `state` types.
Here is the example

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Props {
  ... // your props validation
}

interface State {
  ... // state types
}

class FormExample extends React.Component<Props, State> {... }
```

Comment: or easily in tsconfig.json set noImplicitAny to false

Comment: Are there any resources that go over the above pattern?

Comment: @Pavel Nazarov No! That defeats the purpose of TS.

Comment: @thisismydesign I want to use typescript as a crutch, not an all-body plaster cast (but I'm very happy to define the shape of props).

Comment: @bbsimonbb "Easily" turning off TS features is not a solution, it's bad advice with a lot of side effects that are wholly unclear from that comment. I recommend making exceptions in the code if you have to. Turning off strict checks changes your type-safety from 100% to ???%. Not great.

Comment: Sometimes folks should remember that teams may be doing migrations to TS and that turning off certain TS features allows for a gradual adoption, so this blanket advice of don't do this isn't helpful.

Comment: it's fine to alter tsconfig.json if you are familiar with ts, but until that point, I think it is dangerous and will have unforeseen side effects.

Answer (score 32):

Specifying the type of the constructor parameter resolved this issue in my case.

```
class Clock extends React.Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it defeat the purpose of TypeScript strict typing?

Comment: if the component is not receiving any props, better to say props: {} rather than any

Answer (score 11):

I just got this error on a **functional component**.

In order to get information such as `props.children` as well as custom props, you should do the following.

```
import { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

const Layout: FunctionComponent<{ hello: string }> = props => (
  <div style={layoutStyle}>
    <Header />
    {props.hello}
    {props.children}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

In `tsconfig.json` set `"noImplicitAny": false,`
this worked for me

Comment: just hiding the error message, but it will be better if you suggest some proper solution.

Comment: the proper method will be to mention the type of parameters everywhere. But it's not required around every time compulsorily. This is why we set it as false.

suppose 
catch(err){ console.log(err) here we don't need to specify the type.

Hope you got it.

Answer (score 2):

in type script you need to specify the type of props you are going to send or it takes the default type defined tin @types/react. if you dont want to specify any type then explicitly ask the component to expect state and props of 'any' type.

```
class FormExample extends React.Component<any,any> {
```

the first type argument is for defining the type of props you are expecting , the other is for type of state of the component.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and most straightforward solution I found is using PropsWithChildren:

```js
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'

export const Foo = (props: PropsWithChildren) => {
    return props.children
}
```

Other approaches are listed here though:

https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-children-prop-with-typescript/

Answer (score 0):

Within TypeScript a React.Component is a generic type (aka React.Component<PropType, StateType>). So you want to provide it with (optional) prop and state type parameters.

It would look like this:

```
type MyProps = {
  // using `interface` is also ok
  message: string;
};
type MyState = {
  count: number; // like this
};
class App extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
  state: MyState = {
    // optional second annotation for better type inference
    count: 0,
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.message} {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Don't forget that you can export/import/extend these types/interfaces to reuse them.

`Class Methods`: You could do it in the normal way. Just remember that any arguments for your functions also need to be typed.

This would be the code for a class:

```
class App extends React.Component<{ message: string }, { count: number }> {
  state = { count: 0 };
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={() => this.increment(1)}>
        {this.props.message} {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
  increment = (amt: number) => {
    // like this
    this.setState((state) => ({
      count: state.count + amt,
    }));
  };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In function Component just give **any** at props

```
const CustomImage = (props: any) => {
    return <Image
        {...props}
        loader={customLoader}
        unoptimized={true}
    />
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

## for Functional Components

## just add like this:

## function name (props:any)

## { return (<> </>)  }