# Prop name in functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-component

I am new to React. I have some code snippets written in React in which prop is passed from parent component to child component and I am using functional component ( const arrow function). However, there is a use of **any keyword** which I don't understand.

My parent component:

```
const text = {
  title: "We Made Always Provide Quality Items",
  para1:
    "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident sunt iculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim est. . ",
  para2:
    "Dicta sunt explicabo. nemo enuam eius .",
  thumbnails: [{ src: "" }],
};

const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="about-page">
      <PageHeader
        title={titleContent.title}
        subtitle={titleContent.subtitle}
        btnText="">
        <StatsCards stats={stats} />
      </PageHeader>
      <WhyUs />
      <SideBySide {...text} />
      <Chefs chefs={chefs} />
      <ContentE />
    </div>
  );
};
```

My child component (SideBySide):

```
const SideBySide = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="side-by-side">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="left-side">
          <div className="title">
            <div className="main-title">{props.title}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="description">
            <p>{props.para1}</p>
            <p>{props.para2}</p>
          </div>
          {/* Link to about us */}
          <Link to="/menu">
            <ExploreButton active="link-active">More About Us</ExploreButton>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="right-side">
          <div className="image">
            {props.thumbnails.map((thumbnail: any, index: number) => {
              return (
                <img
                  src={thumbnail.src}
                  alt=""
                  key={index}
                  className={`img-${index}`}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here in sidebyside component, there is a use of `props: any` which i dont understand what it is actually doing.

I just use props keyword until now to pass the props in components and render as props.name as an example.

Comment: That `any` is typescript. Are you trying to use typescript in your project?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52735918/14047838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typescript type which supports all types of fields are receiving from another components

```
const SideBySide = (props: any) => {
```

But if you in react only you can remove type and use like

```
const SideBySide = (props) => {
```

TypeScript example

```
interface PersonProps {
 name: string;
 src: string;
 age: number
}
let person: PersonProps = {
  name: 'John',
  src: 'http://...',
  age: 30
}
```

but if you don't want to define field level type you can use **`any`** like

```
let person: any = {
  name: 'John',
  src: 'http://...',
  age: 30
}
```

For better understanding, refer [TypeScript official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any)

Comment: Hello @akhtarvahid, there is also the use of any in map fuction in thumbail and also the number? What are they doing there??

Comment: @Django-Rocks As i mentioned it's type checking for fields which helps to identify type of fields.

Answer (score 1):

"Any" is a typescript specific type. If you want to use dynamic types (like js) you can use "any". But i think if you use typescript, it is better to describe your types in your component. Like this:

```
const SideBySide = (props: {
 title: string,
 para1: string,
 para2: string,
 thumbnails: Array<{ src: string }>
}) => {
   return (
     ...
   );
 };
```