# Setting types in Components?

Tags: reactjs

Can someone explain what this syntax is doing I have not seen it much

```
type ScrollProps = {
  location: Object,
  elementID?: string
};

class ScrollMemory extends Component<ScrollProps> {
  detectPop: () => void;
  url: Map<string, number>;
```

Original source

https://github.com/ipatate/react-router-scroll-memory/blob/master/src/ScrollMemory.js

Comment: It's 7 lines there, what exactly your question is about?

Comment: It's Typescript

Comment: Flow and Typescript both use the `type` syntax but the example they linked actually uses `flow`. I made the same mistake initially :P

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about Flow ><

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was regular java script since it had a .js extension instead of the usual .ts

Answer (score 1):

Type checking! This is setting up types for your Component. This in turn adds IntelliSense/Typechecking to your code (if your IDE supports it).

The example you linked uses flow. If you want to learn more checkout https://flow.org/

Answer (score 0):

Its a type checking. In TypeScript/flow (for react) you have specify types for your props and states. 
In the given component `ScrollMemory` the `ScrollProps` is type for props passed to it

```
type ScrollProps = {
  location: Object, // type of location must be object
  elementID?: string // elementID is optional, but if passed it should be string
};
```

Related question: [react/typescript: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144169/react-typescript-parameter-props-implicitly-has-an-any-type-error)