# How type material ui props for custom PopperComponent with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-props

I am using [Material ui autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#autocomplete-api) in my React and typescript app.

I need to define a custom popper component because I want to make the popper full-width.

Below is how I can do that:

```
const CustomPopper = (props) => {
    return <Popper {...props} css={styles.popper} placement="bottom-start" />;
```

Then in my `Autocomplete` I can use it like:

```
<Autocomplete PopperComponent={CustomPopper} />
```

I get a Typescript error `Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.` How could I fix this? I can't use `props: any` because my EsLint setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52735288/why-does-parameter-props-implicitly-has-an-any-type)

Comment: Also see [react/typescript: Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49144169/react-typescript-parameter-props-implicitly-has-an-any-type-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need a type for the `props` in the `customPopper` component.

```
const CustomPopper = (props: PopperProps) => { 
    return <Popper {...props} css={styles.popper} placement="bottom-start" />;
}
```

You should be able to extend the `PopperProps` to add whatever other props you may need for your CustomPopper component. Something like this:

```
type MyCustomPopperProps = {
   someCustomProp: string;
} & PopperProps;

const CustomPopper = (props: MyCustomPopperProps) => {  }
```